# What is the suitable type for renderHook in react-testing-library and TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library, react-hooks-testing-library

I wanna test a custom hook with `react-testing-library` therefore, I add this code into beforeEach:

```
let renderedHook ;

beforeEach(() => {
  renderedHook = renderHook(() => useFetch());
});

test('.....', () => {
  expect(renderedHook.current.data).toBe(1);
});
```

the above code works well! but I'm using TypeScript, what's the suitable type for `let renderedHook`  in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your IDE or editor supports the "Go to Definition" feature, you can check the TS type of `renderHook`.

The return type of `renderHook` is [RenderHookResult](https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library/blob/v8.0.0/src/types/index.ts#L57)

E.g.

```
import { Renderer, renderHook, RenderHookResult } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import { useState } from 'react';

const useFetch = () => {
  const [data] = useState(1);
  return { data };
};

let renderedHook: RenderHookResult<unknown, { data: number }, Renderer<unknown>>;

describe('72601993', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    renderedHook = renderHook(() => useFetch());
  });

  test('.....', () => {
    expect(renderedHook.result.current.data).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

package version:

```json
"@testing-library/react-hooks": "^8.0.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the Question is about suitable types, anyone who wants beforeEach functionality in tests and don't want to find suitable types from IDE support, you can create a function like setup

```
const setup = () => {
   const {result} = renderHook(() => useFetch());
}
```

Now you can use it every test without thinking about suitable test and it will show intellisense as well. The usage of the setup is shown below

```
it('should return data equal to 1' => {
  result = setup();
  expect(result.current.data).toBe(1)
})
```